# How to access my profile info from facebook in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, facebook

How can i fetch my profile information from facebook, using facebook api for iphone sdk.
I have successfully able to login using connect method.

after that i have written query something like :

```
- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select uid,name,first_name,middle_name,last_name,affiliations,profile_update_time,timezone,religion,birthday,birthday_date,sex,hometown_location,relationship_status,political,current_location,activities,interests,music,tv,movies,books,quotes,about_me,hs_info,education_history,work_history,status,online_presence,family,username,website,is_blocked,contact_email,email,pic_small,pic_big,pic_square,pic,proxied_email,allowed_restrictions,verified from user where uid == %lld", _session.uid];

    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {

    if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.fql.query"]) {
        NSArray* users = result;
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        }
}
```

when i displayed user(Dictionary) i am not able to get all values from my profile. some values which are already exists and set in my profile have been showing as null.

Why i am not able to get all info from my own profile ? 
or How can i ?

Any idea or help will be well appreciated ?

Comment: here i want to get values from my own profile and after successfull logged in. So i think here there can be never an issue of privacy.
am i right ?

Comment: You should try to reformat your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question, question updated with full implementation details:

[Can't get email address using facebook sdk for IOS and graph api for facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777199/cant-get-email-address-using-facebook-sdk-for-ios-and-graph-api-for-facebook)

Comment: Also, make sure you have permission for email if that is required.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot >you can do some things with facebook api but not all