# Can't get email address using facebook sdk for IOS and graph api for facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the email address from a user. He logs in, I ask permission to access email and he chooses ok. Then I use the graph API from facebook to access the email address.

```
- (void) fbDidLogin
{
  btnLogin.isLoggedIn = TRUE;
  [btnLogin updateImage];

  NSString *theURL = 
  [ [NSString stringWithFormat: 
    @"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@", facebook.accessToken
    ]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
  ];

  NSLog(@"%@", theURL);
  [facebook requestWithGraphPath: theURL andDelegate: self];
}

...

- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData*)data
{
  NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@", response);
  [response release];
}
```

This is how i get the information:

```
- (void) request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
{
  if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
  {
    NSString *email = [result objectForKey: @"email"];
    NSString *name = [result objectForKey: @"name"];
    NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey: @"id"];
    //...
  }
}
```

It gives me only this string: `{ id = "https://graph.facebook.com/me"; }` What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah nevermind, it works. I had to use `@"me"` in `[facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me" andDelegate: self];` instead of the URL.

Comment: @kudor: after calling requestWithGraphPath:@"me", how exactly did you extract the required information like email in your case? I need username.

Comment: I will put the code in my question! You get an `NSDictionary` and you have to get the values from it.

Comment: hi, i tried it out but the response received is "OAuthException": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" so i guess, it doesn't reach request didLoad.

Answer (score 8):

I found answer:

```
 NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_likes",@"offline_access",@"read_stream",@"publish_stream",@"email",nil];

  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me"andParams:params andDelegate:self];
  -(void)facebookLoginScreen:(NSDictionary *)result
   {
        NSLog(%@,[result objectForKey:@"email"]);
   }
```